# How to get the keys from object_construct and list them in a separate column

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like

| ID | ALL_ATTRIBUTES | ALL_FIELDS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name" : "JESSICA"} | {"name"} |
| 2 | {"age": 15, "name": "JOSH"} | {"age", "name"} |

I got this table by doing

```
SELECT ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT("name", NAME, "age", AGE, "city", CITY} AS ALL_ATTRIBUTES, 
OBJECT_KEYS(ALL_ATTRIBUTES) AS ALL_FIELDS 
FROM MY_TABLE
```

The ALL_FIELDS column just lists the keys from ALL_ATTRIBUTES per ID. However I would like to get the keys and list them as

| ID | ALL_ATTRIBUTES | ALL_FIELDS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name" : "JESSICA"} | NAME |
| 2 | {"age": 15, "name": "JOSH" | AGE, NAME |

where they are not in json format. Is there a way I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your result as a string then use [`ARRAY_TO_STRING`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string) :

```
SELECT ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT("name", NAME, "age", AGE, "city", CITY} AS ALL_ATTRIBUTES, 
           ARRAY_TO_STRING(OBJECT_KEYS(ALL_ATTRIBUTES)) AS ALL_FIELDS 
FROM MY_TABLE
```